# 12.04 INFO message on black screen during boot, wifi works fine

Tags: boot, wireless

During boot the purple screen vanishes, replaced by a black screen with one line of text

```
[] INFO@wl_cfg80211_attach Registered CFG80211 phy
```

for a few seconds then returns to normal.  Boot works fine and wifi works fine.

This is the 2nd Ubuntu install on this netbook.  The first time I didn't get this message.  I subsequently screwed the system up badly enough that I decided to do a clean re-install, and this message started appearing.

Everything works, but I really don't want this message showing up during boot.

Prior searching for answers to this problem have involved suggestions to remove the wifi driver and install a different one, but in every case, the questioner reported that it didn't work...However, these questioners also did not have working wifi, and I do.  I'd rather have the message and wifi, but my desired outcome is wifi and no message.

Any help greatly appreciated.