# Error message at startup

Tags: boot, 14.04, laptop

I just installed Ubuntu on my Gateway NE56R41u yesterday. Infact, it dual-boots with Windows 8.1 UEFI, but that has nothing to do with my problem. However, when I turn on my computer, I get an error message that displays for about a second. I don't know what it means, though and it displays for less than a second. Tell me, does it mean anything important? How do I fix it? Also, regardless of if it's important or not or if it is fixable, how can I prevent the message from displaying when I turn my computer on? The error is below:

```
[10.987] info @wl_cfg80211_attach CFG80211 Phy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, that is just a report that it issues while it hasn't loaded the boot screen, if you press any of the f(#) buttons you will see the boot log, and you will see a lot more of those. It is not an error, it is just a report in the log that it successfully loaded a particular sector/file. There really is no way to remove it, as it is just what is in the background while the system boots

Comment: sorry it is impossible to remove, I generally just like it. I disable "quiet boot" in the grub boot option so it displays the whole log, that way if I DO get an error I can see it, plus it gives me a sense of nostalgia having text fly by me on a computer screen :P

Comment: I get that too (http://askubuntu.com/questions/431339/12-04-info-message-on-black-screen-during-boot-wifi-works-fine) it has something to do with the wireless adapter.  Have not found a way to get rid of it yet.

Comment: as I said, though, it is just a report that it found it, not really something you can remove safely because the log is there for a LOT of diagnostic purposes, and really shouldn't be hidden or removed permanently